# How to use multiple inputs for custom Tensorflow model hosted by AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have a trained Tensorflow model that uses two inputs to make predictions. I have successfully set up and deployed the model on AWS Sagemaker.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data='s3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() 
                              + '/R2-model/R2-model.tar.gz',
                             role = role,
                             framework_version = '1.12',
                             py_version='py2',
                             entry_point='train.py')

predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                              instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')

predictor.predict([data_scaled_1.to_csv(),
                   data_scaled_2.to_csv()]
                 )
```

I always receive an error. I could use an AWS Lambda function, but I don't see any documentation on specifying multiple inputs to deployed models. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually build a correct signature when deploying the model first. 
Also, you need to deploy with tensorflow serving.

At inference, you need to also give a proper input format when requesting: basically sagemaker docker server takes the request input and passes it by to tensorflow serving. So, the input needs to match [TF serving inputs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#specifying_input_tensors_in_column_format).

Here is a simple example of deploying a Keras multi-input multi-output model in Tensorflow serving using Sagemaker and how to make inference afterwards:

```
import tarfile

from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder
from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils import predict_signature_def
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from keras import backend as K
import sagemaker
#nano ~/.aws/config
#get_ipython().system('nano ~/.aws/config')
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model


def serialize_to_tf_and_dump(model, export_path):
    """
    serialize a Keras model to TF model
    :param model: compiled Keras model
    :param export_path: str, The export path contains the name and the version of the model
    :return:
    """
    # Build the Protocol Buffer SavedModel at 'export_path'
    save_model_builder = builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
    # Create prediction signature to be used by TensorFlow Serving Predict API
    signature = predict_signature_def(
        inputs={
            "input_type_1": model.input[0],
            "input_type_2": model.input[1],
        },
        outputs={
            "decision_output_1": model.output[0],
            "decision_output_2": model.output[1],
            "decision_output_3": model.output[2]
        }
    )
    with K.get_session() as sess:
        # Save the meta graph and variables
        save_model_builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess=sess, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING], signature_def_map={"serving_default": signature})
        save_model_builder.save()

# instanciate model
model = .... 

# convert to tf model
serialize_to_tf_and_dump(model, 'model_folder/1')

# tar tf model
with tarfile.open('model.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as archive:
    archive.add('model_folder', recursive=True)

# upload it to s3
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
inputs = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path='model.tar.gz')

# convert to sagemaker model
role = get_execution_role()
sagemaker_model = Model(model_data = inputs,
    name='DummyModel',
    role = role,
    framework_version = '1.12')

predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.t2.medium', endpoint_name='MultiInputMultiOutputModel')
```

At inference, here is how to request for predictions:

```
import json
import boto3

x_inputs = ... # list with 2 np arrays of size (batch_size, ...)
data={
    'inputs':{
        "input_type_1": x[0].tolist(),
        "input_type_2": x[1].tolist()
        }
}

endpoint_name = 'MultiInputMultiOutputModel'
client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, Body=json.dumps(data), ContentType='application/json')
predictions = json.loads(response['Body'].read())
```

Comment: This is the correct solution to my problem. I implemented Question Answering model using BERT pretrained model and could not find a way to pass a list of 2 inputs (for 1 example there are 2 inputs: a question and an answer; the label is 0/1) to the endpoint. Creating the signature when saving the model as instructed above and passing the json data format when invoking the endpoint did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to customize the inference functions loaded in the endpoints. In the [SageMaker TF SDK doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html#) here you can find that there are two options for SageMaker TensorFlow deployment:

- [Python Endpoint](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_python.rst), that is the default, check if modifying the
  `input_fn` can accomodate your inference scheme
- [TF Serving
  endpoint](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.rst)

You can diagnose error in Cloudwatch (accessible through the sagemaker endpoint UI), choose the most appropriate serving architecture among the above-mentioned two and customize the inference functions if need be

Comment: I got as far as modifying the input_fn to split a serialized csv into two inputs, but nowhere in the docs does it say how to send multiple inputs to the model.

Comment: That's because the doc is model agnostic. How would you do this out of SageMaker? what your inference call would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Only the TF serving endpoint supports multiple inputs in one inference request. You can follow the documentation here to deploy a TFS endpoint - 
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.rst