# How to use multiple inputs for custom Tensorflow2 model hosted by AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I need to create an endpoint in sagemaker for a multi input model, the way to do it with Tensorflow 1 has been answered in this question [How to use multiple inputs for custom Tensorflow model hosted by AWS Sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482322/how-to-use-multiple-inputs-for-custom-tensorflow-model-hosted-by-aws-sagemaker)
Does anyone know how to do same with Tensorflow 2?

Comment: I have found this to solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142040/tensorflow-2-0-how-to-change-the-output-signature-while-using-tf-saved-model